# (Google) font for the visually impaired

Tags: google-webfonts

Could you please recommend a font, preferably from Google, suitable for the poor sighted (12/20 vision) and looks good for everybody with 16px in size? Regular Latin character sets are sufficient.

What do you think about 'Source Code Pro' (16px/Normal 400), I think it looks nice, but I am not sure...

Thank's for reading.
S.M.A

Answer (score 0):

You may like some of the fonts available from Proggy Programming Fonts. I like the "Clean" font for my use but it may not scale that large and still look nice so I would suggest you check out the "Crisp" font lower down the page.

[Proggy Fonts](http://www.proggyfonts.net/)

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using something simpler: Here is the CSS code is it could help someone else:     {font-family: sans-serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;font-size: 24px;text-transform: none;text-decoration: none;letter-spacing: 0em;word-spacing: 0em;line-height: 1.4;}'